# Set multiple dates to calendar

Tags: java, android, android-calendar

I am novice using  calendar in java. I am trying to set multiple dates to my calendar (for Android) but I am doing wrong because I only watch the last one.

I have try like this:

```
 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2015);
                cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.MARCH);
                cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 30);
                cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2015);
                cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.MARCH);
                cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 20);
Date dateRepresentation = cal.getTime();
```

And like this:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2015);
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.MARCH);
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 30);

        Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal2.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2015);
        cal2.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.MARCH);
        cal2.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 20);

        Date dateRepresentation = cal.getTime();
        Date dateRepresentation2 = cal2.getTime();
```

Somebody can help me? Thank you

Comment: You should clarify "I am doing wrong because I only watch the last one."

Comment: have you tried getSelectedDates()

Comment: follow this https://github.com/square/android-times-square/blob/master/library/src/com/squareup/timessquare/CalendarPickerView.java

Comment: When I run the calendar view only has the last one, in my example 20/03/2015

Comment: There is not getSelectedDates(), how do you use this?